# Moment misunderstanding utcOffset

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm working with moment and moment-timezone and I don't get it. Can anyone explain me why this happens?

THIS (which is what I want):

```
moment('2018-11-28T00:00:00.000-02:00').toISOString()
```

Prints `2018-11-28T02:00:00.000Z`

BUT:

```
moment('2018-11-28T00:00:00.000').zone('-02:00').toISOString()
moment('2018-11-28T00:00:00.000').utcOffset('-02:00').toISOString()
```

Both print `2018-11-27T23:00:00.000Z`

PD: My zone is GMT+1.

Why are different? it is not supposed to be equals?
How do I set the offset (not in the constructor but with a method after I have de moment object)?

Thanks! BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you want to keep the existing time of day when using utcOffset method. It accepts a second parameter, which is a boolean. As the documentation says:

> Passing true will keep the same local time, but at the expense of choosing a different point in Universal Time.

```
// "2018-11-28T02:00:00.000Z"
moment('2018-11-28T00:00:00.000').utcOffset('-02:00', true).toISOString();
```

For more information check the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)